# R-programming. Percentiles

Tags: r, matrix, percentile, quantile

So I have estimated 1000 cash flows 10 years ahead. These cash flows are contained in a `1000*10` matrix.

For analytical purposes I want to examine the different percentiles/quantiles in terms of cash flows.

Part of my R-code

```
plot(timeline, TOTKS[1,], ylim=range(-15000000,100000000), type="l", ylab="Cash Flow", xlab="year")
for (i in 1:total.simulations){
lines(timeline, TOTKS[i,])}
```

Example:

1. I want to color the 10 % lowest cash flows in the plot above.
2. I want to examine those 10 % in a new matrix.

Any Suggestion?

Regards

Comment: what is timeline? what do you mean by 1000 cashflows 10 years ahead? 1000 cashFlows per year?

Comment: try the `quantile` function. You can select the Ubound for the lowest using something like `quantile(myvals,seq(0.1,0.9,0.1))[1]`

Answer (score 0):

By "lowest cashflows" do you mean "lowest total cash flow over all the years" or "lowest single point of cash flow over the years" or ... ?

I'm guessing the former, though what you mean might be something I didn't guess at all.  :)

Also, I don't have any data from you, so what's below is guesswork based on your description. In future, you'll get better answers faster if you can put some sample or fake data (in the correct structure) into the question using `dput()`. But I hope this gets you started.

## Edited - changed 10 lowest to lowest 10%

Due to inattention and insufficient coffee, I answered the wrong question. Fixed, I think.

First, find the ten lowest total cash flows. Add up the columns:

```
total.cashflow <- drop(colSums(TOTKS, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Then find which are the 10% lowest:

```
rank.cashflow.le10 <- which(
    total.cashflow <= qualtile(total.cashflow, 0.1)
    )
```

Add them to the plot:

```
matlines(timeline, TOTKS[,rank.cashflow.le10], col="red")
```

To examine those as a separate matrix (but you might not need to, with a vector of indicies)

```
low10TOTKS <- TOTKS[,rank.cashflow.le10]
```

Hope that helps.